# How to link images to attachment.php

Tags: attachments

I have custom `attachment.php`, I want to give link for images in `single.php` so if user click that images, will redirect to `attachment.php` is that possible?

Here is the example of code.

```
<a href="link for redirect to attachment.php"><img src="folder/logo.png"></a>
```

Thank you before

Comment: I'm sure you are facing the same problem. See **Edit #2** [here in this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166353/22728)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "redirect" there. `attachment.php` is meant to be used as theme template file. Loading it directly it won't be able to access WordPress core properly.

In usual WordPress mechanics you can use [`get_attachment_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_attachment_link/) to form URL itself or [`wp_get_attachment_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_attachment_link/) for whole link HTML.

Comment: So like this if I am use your code? <a href="<?php wp_get_attachment_link();?>"><img src="folder/logo.png"></a> . But the link of images still like the_permalink .