# How to link a PDF file to a category URL

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, media-library

I am not sure if it is possible to do this but I have a category called case-studies into which I write individual posts to summarize a case-study - for the sake of this question let's give a title of cs1. This gives me a url of /case-studies/cs1. There will be more than one case study created.

I also have a PDF file containing the complete case-study (call it cs1.pdf) which I could load up into the media library or create a separate folder with a nicer URL. However in both cases the URL would not be related to the category.

What I would really like is to load up all the different case studies PDFs (either in the media library or a separate folder) and get a URL of either /case-studies/cs1.pdf or case-studies/cs1/cs1.pdf.

I do know I can't just create a folder called case-studies as this will then mess up using /case-studies to display the case-studies category page however I wondered if there might be a work around to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

If your theme has an attachment template (`attachment.php`) and you upload your page/post-specific media items, then you will get a page/post-specific media attachment URL.
[image: add an image from post/page]

Suppose you are adding/editing your post/page on Case Study (i.e. `cs1`), so your post/page URL will be (if `post-name` permalink structure is enabled):

```
http://example.com/cs1/
```

If you upload an image or a PDF file in this article, the image/PDF file's URL will become:

<strike>`http://example.com/cs1/cs1.pdf`</strike> (see 'edit' below)

So you can have a nice URL that's perfectly saying what it is and where it belongs to.

#### EDIT

1. You have to have the permalink structure to `post-name`. You can do it from admin panel Settings » Permalinks.
2. You can have a look how an attachment file can be from TwentyFifteen's `image.php`. You can use `image.php` for that too. I've tested using [this one](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nano-progga/blob/master/image.php) and it's completely working.
3. When inserting the PDF file into the post/page remember to link it to the attachment page [see edit#2 here in this linked answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166353/22728). And I did say one thing wrong you will get an URL `http://example.com/cs1/cs1` (there would be no extension in the URL) :)

And now it's tested. :)

Comment: I created an attachment.php using a copy of single.php (I think this is the right thing to do?) but the resulting link was a url of news/case-studies/cs1/attachment/pdf1/. This clicks through to a blank article with the heading of pdf1.

Comment: I updated my answer